# How to add multiple if clause in Scala For Loop

Tags: scala

Please let me know how can I add two if clause in a for loop with or option.
  **for (name <- names **(if name.startsWith("S") ||
          if name.endsWith("B".toLowerCase()) )** ) println(name)**

```
object ScalaList {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val x = List(1,2,3,4,5)
      val x1 =List.range(10, 20)
      val x2 = 1::2::33::44::Nil
      val x3 = 100 :: x //(Prepending 100 in List x)
      val x4 = x1 ::: x2  //(Merging two list)
      val x5 = List.concat(x1 ,x2) //(Merging two list)

      x5.foreach {println} //Iterating list
      var sum=0
      var k = x.foreach (sum += _)

      val names =List("Sanjeeb","Hari","Adu","Bob")
      for (name <- names) println(name)
      for (name <- names if name.startsWith("S")                // <-- here is my if
          if name.endsWith("B".toLowerCase())  ) println(name)  // <-------


    }

}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. What is it you want this code to do? What error did you get from the compiler? At first blush, it looks like some { and } could help here.

Comment: Hello,I just want to add 2 if condition in For Loop. for (name <- names (if name.startsWith("S") || if name.endsWith("B".toLowerCase()) ) ) println(name) I need those person starting with S or ending with b. Is it clear sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use braces:

```
for {
  name <- names 
  if name.startsWith("S")
  if name.endsWith("B".toLowerCase())
} {
  println(name)
}
```

It makes for nice notation when you have multiple things you're iterating over or multiple `if`s or those things mixed together.

A semicolon between the `if`s would also work:

```
for (name <- names if name.startsWith("S"); if name.endsWith("B".toLowerCase())) println(name)
```

Comment: When you write two if statement (Line after Line) Is is referring to and clause or OR clause. I mean to ask your statements means name.startsWith("S") && name.endsWith("B".toLowerCase()) ????

Answer (score 1):

You really needs two `if`s ?

```
if (name.startsWith("S") || name.endsWith("B".toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Can you please help me in below comand. While executing in eclipse below output is coming.var temp = "sanjeeb|panda"
    println(temp.split("\\|")) [Ljava.lang.String;@c8ec3bc

Comment: Result of split function is string array `String[]`. In Java I would use `Arrays.toString(temp)`